# Is it possible to relate two weak entities each other?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

In ER diagrams, is it possible to relate two weak entities each other? If possible, how can uniquely identify records in them?

Comment: Please give examples of what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: For an example, "children of employees" table in a company database is a weak entity. It depends on the "Employees" table. Is is possible to relate another weak entity to "children of employees" table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Consider the following ER diagram in which invoices are composed of lines, and receipts are decomposed into corresponding lines which are allocated to invoice lines. Multiple receipt lines can be allocated to the same InvoiceLine. It's perhaps a bit contrived but it'll serve as an example.

[image: Relationship between weak entity sets]

The `InvoiceLine` entity set is identified by `(InvoiceNumber, LineNumber)`. Similarly, the `ReceiptLine` entity set is identified by `(ReceiptNumber, LineNumber)`.

The determinant of a relationship between any entity sets is a combination of the determinants of the entity sets in many-roles. It doesn't matter whether the entity sets are weak or regular, or whether you have two or more entity sets involved in the relationship. In the case of 1:1 (or 1:1:1, etc) relationship, any of the entity sets involved can be used as a determinant.

In our example, `ReceiptLine` is the only entity set in a many-role (indicated by an N next to the `Paid` relationship diamond). This means the relationship is determined by the determinant of `ReceiptLine`, which is `(ReceiptNumber, LineNumber)`.

If we translate our ER diagram to a tabular model, we get the following:

[image: Table diagram implementing relationship between weak entity sets]

I translated it directly to help you see the correspondence between the diagrams, but in practice we could denormalize the `Paid` relationship relation into the `ReceiptLine` entity relation for a simpler physical model. That can only be done for relationships with a single determining entity set, so it's important that you understand the general approach first.

[image: Simplified tabular model]